# How can I cure mypy & Pylance objection to a function that returns a Callable?

Tags: python, mypy, pylance

I have an Abstract Base Class called [`Feature`](https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/blob/4dec70c9ef12021f3c3e8aa4b70027a3a06a02b5/jstark/feature.py#L67) with an `@abstractmethod` **aggregator** that returns a Callable:

```py
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def aggregator(self) -> Callable[[Column], Column]:
        pass
```

I am calling this method from another method on the same class:

```py
    @property
    def column(self) -> Column:
        return self.aggregator()(self.columnExpression()).alias(self.feature_name)
```

I have a concrete implementation of `Feature` called [`GrossSpendFeature`](https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/blob/4dec70c9ef12021f3c3e8aa4b70027a3a06a02b5/jstark/gross_spend_feature.py#L10) and a test that instantiates `GrossSpendFeature`

```py
def test_gross_spend(dataframe_of_purchases):
    first = (
        PurchasingFeatureGenerator(as_at=date.today(), df=dataframe_of_purchases)
        .get_df()
        .first()
    )
    assert first is not None
    assert float(first["GrossSpend_2d1"]) == 5.5
```

https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/blob/4dec70c9ef12021f3c3e8aa4b70027a3a06a02b5/tests/test_purchasing_feature_generator.py#L39

The test succeeds:

> tests/test_purchasing_feature_generator.py::test_gross_spend PASSED

https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/actions/runs/3560259264/jobs/5980174479#step:7:38

So far, so good. Unfortunately both mypy and Pylance (which is a static type checker from Microsoft that I use in Visual Studio Code) both complain about the code above that calls **aggregator**.

Here is what Pylance says:

> Expected 1 more positional argument

[image]

and mypy reports similar:

> jstark/feature.py:108: error: Too few arguments

https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/actions/runs/3560259264/jobs/5980174250#step:4:735

**aggregator** only has one argument, `self`, so I don't understand why these errors are appearing. I am hoping someone here can enlighten me and also tell me how to alleviate it.

Comment: Wait, `aggregator` is a **property**, so `self.aggregator` is already a `Callable[[Column], Column]` - and this cannot be called with zero arguments. Either remove `property` decorator or empty parens on call site. (Sorry if I'm misreading something, just a quick glance). I'd suppose that implementation lacks `property` decorator on `aggregator` definition as opposed to abstract one, so the actual test passes.

Comment: [It does.](https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/blob/4dec70c9ef12021f3c3e8aa4b70027a3a06a02b5/jstark/gross_spend_feature.py#L16) Why doesn't `mypy` point out this error? I vote to close this as typo, because decorator mismatch on abc vs impl shouldn't be useful for future readers.

Comment: you're right, my mistake. I removed the `@property` decorator and the error went away. Can't even remember why I put it there in the first place. thank you.